# Jersey and AsyncResponse vs. Redirects

Tags: heroku, asynchronous, jersey, jax-rs

Currently I am using Jersey 1.0 and about to switch to 2.0. For REST requests the may last over a second or two I use the following pattern:

1. Client calls GET or PUT
2. Server returns a polling URL to the client
3. The client polls the URL until it gets a redirect to the completed resource

Pretty standard and straightforward. However, I noticed that Jersey 2.0 has an AsyncResponse capability. But it looks like this is done with no changes on the wire. In other words, the client still blocks for the result while the server is asynchronously processing the request.

So what good is this? Should I be using it instead of my current asynchronous approach for calls >1 second? Or is it really just to keep the connections freed on the server for calls that would be only a few hundred milliseconds?

I want my server to be as scalable as possible but the approach I use now can be tedious for the client. AsyncResponse seems super simple but I'm not sure how it would work for something like a heroku service where you want very short connection times.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncResponse presumably gives you more scalability within the web app server for standard standard requests in terms of thread pooling resources, but I don't think it changes anything about the client experience which will continue to block on read on their connection. Therefore, if you already implemented a polling solution from your client side, this won't add much of any value to you imho.

Comment: Right, so I'm guessing AsyncResponse resume, suspend, etc. would not work well with multiple stateless servers? IOW, you can't suspend on one web dyno and resume on another.

Comment: I wouldn't think so as the client request and connection is still pending to the same server port.